# Within CR can you combine multiple rows into one?

Tags: merge, crystal-reports

Within Crystal Reports I am attempting to consolidate data into a single row for Billing purposes, rather than one row for each billable charge listed on the Master Invoice.  Below is the example:

```
ORDER#  ORDERID SHIPTO      CARRIER     SHIP SM PACKAGE HANDLING    LABELING   TOTAL
1234    54321   Customer1   UPS GROUND  $5.00                                  $5.00    
1234    54321   Customer1   UPS GROUND                  $0.60                  $0.60
1234    54321   Customer1   UPS GROUND                              $0.50      $0.50

ORDER#  ORDERID SHIPTO      CARRIER     SHIP SM PACKAGE HANDLING    LABELING    TOTAL
1234    54321   Customer1   UPS GROUND  $5.00           $0.60       $0.50       $6.10
```

Answer (score 0):

In the report, you will have to group by order#, orderID, shipto, carrier.
Click on Insert --> Summary.
Choose the field to the summarize from the dropdown.
Under "Calculate this summary" choose "Sum" from dropdown.
Change the "Summary location" to Group #4 footer. Hit Okay.
Hide the Details section.
Drag  the order#, orderID, shipto, carrier in the Group#4 footer section.